# opencv.js floodFill Function in javascript has different result with opencvSharp

Tags: javascript, html, opencv

The `opencv.js` is from

[here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/opencv.js)

The image is here:

[image: The image is here]

I have try to using `bfs` for flood it and using the function with same `parms`, but seems the function `floodFill` is only flood a little even if i change the `loDiff` and `upDiff`? Is any one know is this a bug in `opencv.js` or something else?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello OpenCV.js</title>
    <!-- 使用js版的opencv -->
    <script
      async
      src="opencv.js"
      onload="onOpenCvReady();"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello OpenCV.js</h2>
    <p id="status">OpenCV.js is loading...</p>
    <div>
      <button onclick="btnFloodclick()"> flood </button>
      <button onclick="btnBfsFloodClick()">flood bfs</button>
      <canvas id="canvasOutput" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;"></canvas>
      <canvas id="canvasOutput2" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <img src="./0.png" id="my_img" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function onOpenCvReady() {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "OpenCV.js is ready.";
        lodiff = cv.Scalar.all(0),updiff = cv.Scalar.all(60);
        btnBfsFloodClick();
        btnFloodclick();
      }

      let lodiff,updiff;

      function btnBfsFloodClick(){
        let canvas = document.getElementById("my_img");
        let mat = cv.imread(canvas);
        let canvasCoords={x:492,y:461+1};

        let p = new cv.Point(parseInt(canvasCoords.x), parseInt(canvasCoords.y));
        let sc = new cv.Scalar.all(255);

        cv.cvtColor(mat,mat,cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);


        //#region  try it in bfs 
        

        let matChan = mat.channels();
        let seedPointPixelVal = mat.data[p.y * mat.cols * matChan + p.x * matChan];
        console.log(seedPointPixelVal);
        //console.log(mat.rows + " " + mat.cols);
        let set = new Set();
        let que = [p];
        let posi = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]]
        while(que.length!=0) {
          let sz = que.length;
          for(let i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            let cur = que.pop();
            set.add(JSON.stringify(cur));
        
            mat.data[cur.y * mat.cols * matChan + cur.x * matChan] = 255
            // 分别计算4个相邻的角
            for(let j = 0; j < posi.length; j++) {
              nxt = {x:cur.x+posi[j][0], y:cur.y+posi[j][1]};
              if(nxt.x < mat.cols && nxt.x >= 0
              && nxt.y < mat.rows && nxt.y >= 0) 
              {
                if(set.has(JSON.stringify(nxt)))
                {
                  continue;
                }
            
                if(Math.abs(mat.data[nxt.y * mat.cols * matChan + nxt.x * matChan] - seedPointPixelVal) + lodiff[0] < updiff[0] + lodiff[0])
                  que.push(nxt);
                else{}
                  //console.warn("===")
              }
              else{
                //console.warn("****" + nxt.x + " " + nxt.y);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput2', mat);
        mat.delete();
        //mask.delete();
        return;
        //#endregion
      }

      function btnFloodclick(){
        let canvas = document.getElementById("my_img");
        let mat = cv.imread(canvas);
        let canvasCoords={x:492,y:461+1};

        let p = new cv.Point(parseInt(canvasCoords.x), parseInt(canvasCoords.y));
        let sc = new cv.Scalar.all(255);

        cv.cvtColor(mat,mat,cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);

        const mask = new cv.Mat(mat.rows + 2, mat.cols + 2, cv.CV_8U, cv.Scalar.all(0));

       
    
        // 看看当前p范围内的像素大小
        // y-->row(height) x-->col(width)
        let src = mat;
        for(let i = p.y-5; i <= p.y+5; i++){
          let x = "";
          for(let j = p.x-5; j <= p.x+5; j++) {
            let R = src.data[i * src.cols * src.channels() + j * src.channels()];
            if(j == p.x && i == p.y){
              x += "!";
            }
            x += "[" + R + "]" + " ";
          }
          console.log(x);
        }

        console.log("------------");
        console.log(mask.data);
        console.log("------------");
        cv.floodFill(mat, mask, p, sc, lodiff, updiff);

        console.log("==============================");
        src = mask;
        for(let i = p.y-5; i <= p.y+5; i++) {
          let x = "";
          for(let j = p.x-5; j <= p.x+5; j++) {
            let R = src.data[i * src.cols * src.channels() + j * src.channels()];
            if(j-1 == p.x && i-1 == p.y){
              x += "!";
            }
            x += "[" + R + "]" + " ";
          }
          console.log(x);
        }


        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', mat);
        console.log("------------");
        console.log(mask.data);
        mat.delete();
        mask.delete();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the same result in opencv function floodFill